# Angular + Laravel 5.5 API

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have two projects in different directories. The first one is my Angular app and the second one is Laravel 5.5 back-end. I have created an API which i want to call in my Angular app. When i try to get the API in Angular i get this response:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at http://localhost/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-
Origin’ missing).
```

Both projects are locally and i access Laravel from `http://localhost` and Angular from `http://localhost:4200`

I want to be able to get and post data locally to test my application. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some CORS middleware for your API requests, that allows your client to make cross origin requests to your API routes.

You could use this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Or implement it yourself it's pretty easy.

Comment: i use laravel-cors and worked fine in my localhost but after deploy to my docker my browser return corb cors error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own CORS middleware, you can create a middleware with a `handle()` function like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
```

Then in your */app/Http/Kernel.php* add the middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` array.
Finally you need to add this middleware to your routes.

I got this explanation from this video: [23.- Curso de Angular 4 con Laravel 5. Uso de Cors para conectar APIs.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq9AFIuEv0k)